# Within a Class how do I check if the Passed in Variable is a specific varable

Tags: python

```
def is_stat_enhanced(self, stat):
    if stat == hasattr(self, 'strength_grade'):
        if self.enhanced_strength == True:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    elif stat == hasattr(self, 'endurance_grade'):
        if self.enhanced_endurance == True:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    elif stat == hasattr(self, 'agility_grade'):
        if self.enhanced_agility == True:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    elif stat == hasattr(self, 'reflex_grade'):
        if self.enhanced_reflex == True:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    elif stat == hasattr(self, 'speed_grade'):
        if self.enhanced_speed == True:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return print("error with check enhanced")
```

I'm basically trying to tie two variables together, this would be a check should I ever have to do so. I assume there's not a __name__ function for variables.

I'm not 100% set on doing it this way if there is something simpler that can be done to achieve the same effect.

[Edit 1]
I'm quite new to both programming and StackOverflow

The function will only ever be called for specific use cases so `Stat` should be `self.strength_grade` where strength can be changed out for the other "stats"

I'm trying to compare the Variable itself rather than the value because multiple variables can have the value it can be assigned.

-- Seems hasattr isn't going to work, was my best guess.

Comment: what value is `stat` supposed to have? can you make an example of calling your function and the expected result?

Comment: It may be easier to put all of this data into a `dict` rather than trying to work with attributes that may or may not exist.

Comment: Note that all of the inner `if/else` blocks can be simplified.  For example: `if self.enhanced_strength == True: ...` -> `return self.enhanced_strength`

Comment: `hasattr()` is going to return either True or False.  If the `stat` parameter is anything other than those two values, your function will do nothing.